# Obtaining counts of factor variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of mostly factor variables that I'd like to summarize the counts for in R using the `summarise` function from dplyr. This is from a pre and post treatment scenario so some levels might be missing in the post, depending on responses.

I can get both counts individually like so:

```
bla = data.frame(pre = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), post = c("b", "d", "a", "a", "e"))
bla$pre = as.factor(bla$pre)
bla$post = as.factor(bla$post)
bla %>% group_by(pre) %>% summarise(Count = n())
bla %>% group_by(post) %>% summarise(Count = n())
```

which yields:

| pre | Count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 1 |
| d | 1 |
| e | 1 |

| post | Count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 1 |
| d | 1 |
| e | 1 |

But what I am after is:

| Level | pre Count | post Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 1 | 1 |
| c | 1 | 0 |
| d | 1 | 1 |
| e | 1 | 1 |

Comment: For your expected, may be you need a join `bla %>% count(Level = pre, name = 'pre Count') %>% full_join(bla %>% count(Level = post, name = 'post Count'))`

Comment: Slight variation: `left_join(count(bla, level = pre, name = "pre"), count(bla, level = post, name = "post")) |> mutate(across(pre:post, ~replace_na(., 0)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bla %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "name", values_to = "Level") %>% 
  mutate(name = paste(name, "Count")) %>% 
  count(name, Level) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=name, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  arrange(Level)
```

```
    Level `post Count` `pre Count`
  <fct>        <int>       <int>
1 a                2           1
2 b                1           1
3 c                0           1
4 d                1           1
5 e                1           1
```

Answer (score 1):

in base R

```
xtabs(~., stack(bla))

      ind
values pre post
     a   1    2
     b   1    1
     c   1    0
     d   1    1
     e   1    1
```

or even

```
sapply(bla, \(x)table(factor(x, unique(unlist(bla)))))

  pre post
a   1    2
b   1    1
c   1    0
d   1    1
e   1    1
```

If you need a dataframe:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(~., stack(bla)))
  pre post
a   1    2
b   1    1
c   1    0
d   1    1
e   1    1
```